# Ограничение подключения по IP за 1 секунду

Tags: php

есть задача ограничить количество подключений за 1 секунду с одного IP адреса, сервис предоставляет API и нужно ограничить подключения пользователей , сделать за 1 секунду к примеру 2 подключения

подскажите можно ли как-то это реализовать без использования БД и без вреда на производительность так как эта проверка не должна повлиять на скорость подключений?

у меня были мысли записывать в файлик на небольшое промежуток времени и в файлике считать все ип адреса и время ну не вариант

Comment: Чем не угодила БД? БД самый оптимальный и производительный вариант. Особенно если использовать HEAP таблицу и построить индекс по времени.

Comment: как мне кажется,  что это не самый быстрый вариант это же нужно записать в базу а после еще вытянуть и посчитать ... вызывает сомнение , а есть какието  примеры "HEAP таблицы" ?

Comment: Поддержу — лучше БД, С файлами есть большая проблема при одновременном использовании: когда будет множество одновременных открытие/блокировка/запись/закрытие. Это часто приводит к потерям информации.

Comment: В nginx есть целый большой модуль, который делает все нужные ограничения https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/